# Is the NWT translation of Σαβαὼθ in Romans 9:29 reasonable?

Tags: greek, romans

Σαβαὼθ, *Sabaoth* is the Greek transcription of צְבָאוֹת, plural of צָבָא=army, in a name applied to God κύριος Σ.=יהוָה צְבָאוֹת ***Yahweh Lord of the Armies, Lord of Hosts***.<sup>`1`</sup>

Paul uses this word in Romans:

> καὶ καθὼς προείρηκεν Ἠσαΐας εἰ μὴ κύριος **Σαβαὼθ** ἐγκατέλιπεν ἡμῖν σπέρμα ὡς Σόδομα ἂν ἐγενήθημεν καὶ ὡς Γόμορρα ἂν ὡμοιώθημεν (GNT and TR)

> And as Isaiah said before: “Unless the Lord of **Sabaoth** had left us a seed, We would have become like Sodom, And we would have been made like Gomorrah." (Romans 9:29 NKJV)

The NWT looks past the actual Greek to render the word based on the Hebrew meaning:

> Also, just as Isaiah had said aforetime: "Unless Jehovah **of armies** had left a seed to us, we should have become just like Sodom and we should have been made just like Gomorrah." (NWT)

Is this a reasonable translation?

---

<sub>1. Fredrick William Danker, *A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature*, The University Chicago Press, 2000, p. 909</sub>

Comment: If Romans 9:29 quotes Isaiah 1:9, why would it not be? Isaiah 1:29 YLT says Unless Jehovah of Hosts had left to us a remnant, Shortly -- as Sodom we had been, To Gomorrah we had been like!. The Hebrew word tseva·ʼohthʹ, “armies,” is transliterated Sa·ba·othʹ in Greek.

Comment: @AlexBalilo The Greek can be rendered into English and an accurate translation should reflect the original Greek, without assuming Paul intended something different. This is relevant since the LXX shows צְּבָאֽוֹת can be rendered in different ways: 1) Σαβαὼθ (i.e. Isaiah 1:9) 2) παντοκράτωρ (i.e. Amos 3:13) 3) δυνάμεων (i.e. Zephaniah 2:9). Even more to the question of reasonableness is in Isaiah, צְּבָאֽוֹת is never translated as δυνάμεων, forces. So it appears the NWT's use of this meaning not only ignores Paul, but the LXX as well.

Comment: Is the original language of the OT Hebrew or Greek? If Isaiah 1:29 was the verse quoted in Romans 9:29, what was mistranslated with the NWT?

Comment: @AlexBalilo The original language was Hebrew and the first translation of the Hebrew was Greek, not English. The Hebrew scholars who translated into Greek understood the word had at least three different meanings:  Σαβαὼθ Sabaoth; παντοκράτωρ almighty; δυνάμεων, armies/forces. If the NT is inspired, then the Holy Spirit affirmed the meaning in Isaiah as Σαβαὼθ. Moreover, as far as I can tell nowhere does the LXX understand צְּבָאֽוֹת as armies/forces in Isaiah. It is consistently treated as Σαβαὼθ.

Comment: The WEB and ISV has it as "armies" . The Hebrew word tseva·ʼohthʹ, “armies,” is transliterated Sa·ba·othʹ in Greek. What are the other "reasonable" meaning/translation that you know that this word have?

Comment: @RevelationLad - After revisiting your question and Dottard's answer, my eye was drawn to how the NWT translates Romans 9:5. Speaking of the Christ, the NWT says "sprang according to the flesh: God, who is over all, be blessed forever. Amen." This is quite different to how the KJV and the NIV translate that verse.  I realise this is not what you asked here, but I was hoping someone who understands Greek could ask a question to establish if the NWT has translated Romans 9:5 accurately.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the OP has correctly quoted BDAG and its meaning of Σαβαὼθ, Sabaoth.  The essential thrust of this word is a title of God as head of the armies of heaven which is also made explicit in places such as Rev 19:11-16.

In the OT, the title, "LORD/Lord of Hosts/Armies" is frequent, eg, Jer 46:10, Zech 1:3, 8:9, 14:21, 19:3, Isa 18:7, Hag 1:14, 2:23, etc.

The Hebrew word translated, "Host(s)" is צָבָא (tsaba) which means, "army, war, warfare" and is applied to:

- earthly armies, Gen 21:22, 32, 26:26, Ex 6:26, 12:51, etc
- Israel's armies, Ex 7:4, 12:7, Num 1:3, etc
- Heavenly Armies, see above list.

BDAG notes that the Greek Σαβαὼθ is an attempted transliteration of the Hebrew צָבָא (tsaba).  Thus, the Greek refers directly to the Hebrew both in Rom 9:29 and in James 5:4.

The translation of Rom 9:29 can be classified as follows:

- "Lord of Armies": NLT, NASB, ISV, NET, WEB, etc.
- "Lord Sabaoth": KJV, NKJV, ASV, DRB, YLT, ERV, etc
- "Lord of Hosts": ESV, BSB, BLB, CSB, HCSB, LSV, NAB, NRSV, NHEB, LET, etc.
- "Lord Almighty": NIV, GNT, etc.

A very similar list could be compiled for James 5:4 to give, Lord of Hosts", "Lord of Armies", "Lord Sabaoth".

Therefore, in the case of Rom 9:29, I see no difficulty with the NWT rendering of the verse.

Comment: I apologize. My down vote was a mistake.

Comment: I have withdrawn my downvote.

Comment: @AlexBalilo - many thanks for your kindness